# Ant <Sql> and <exec> sqlcmd - Different Outputs

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ant, sqlcmd

I have one .sql file that is execute using ant, when I execute it with the  tag I recived a different output as when i used  calling "sqlcmd".

sql tag output:

```
  [sql] Executing resource: C:\SqlTesting\TestScriptDependencies\Executor.sql
  [sql] Failed to execute:  Use Library Exec CallSelectSP
  [sql] com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name'Libraty.dbo.libraryDocumentType'.
  [sql] 0 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
```

exec tag output:

```
 [exec] First SP
 [exec] Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server MyPC-PC, Procedure getFirstDocumentType, Line 3
 [exec] Invalid object name 'Libraty.dbo.libraryDocumentType'.
 [exec] Second SP
 [exec] Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server MyPC-PC, Procedure badSP, Line 3
 [exec] Invalid object name 'Libraty.dbo.libraryDocumentType'.
```

And this is the .sql file.

```
Print 'First SP'
Exec getFirstDocumentType
Print 'Second SP'
Exec badSP
Go
```

I wonder if it is a way of the SQL tag reproduce the same output as the EXEC tag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the first one is submitting the whole script as a single batch via jdbc. Whereas the second appears to be sending each sql statement via sqlcmd - hence the print statements succeed (and result in synchronized output - which is not always guaranteed with print - `raiserror(str, 10, 1)` with nowait; is the only guarantee of timely messaging) and both sp calls are attempted, each producing their own (sql) error.